# How to avoid reset of Screen.MenuFont settings when Windows text scaling is changed?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl

In the constructor of the main form the MenuFont is modified like this

```
Screen->MenuFont->Name = "Segoe UI";
Screen->MenuFont->Size = 11;
```

I have noticed that the font changes (gets smaller, perhaps also other font) under certain circumstances. For example, when the scaling of texts is changed in the Windows display settings (Windows 10). Setting the scaling back does not fix the font.

Why does this happens? Is there a possibility to avoid this or detect the change of the font and set it back?

Comment: Menu font size is controlled by the OS. You can not prevent a size change when the system settings are changed.

Comment: If the user changes the screen scaling factor, why would you want to prevent their change? It's the very opposite of the way an application should behave. If the user wants larger fonts, let them have their larger fonts.

Comment: The change of the scaling is not the only situation where this happens. Also the menu font gets smaller, even if the scaling in the OS is raised. Setting the scaling back to default does not set the font back to the previous size.